# Error when setting UISlider's Min and Max values

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I am playing videos from the user's library in my app. I use this method in `ViewDidLoad()` to get the video:

```
fileprivate let imageManager = PHImageManager()
fileprivate var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
fileprivate var player:AVPlayer?
fileprivate var videoView:UIView?

imageManager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: videoAsset, options: options, resultHandler: { playerItem, info in
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                guard self.playerLayer == nil else { return }

                self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)

                self.videoView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
                self.videoView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                self.playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
                self.playerLayer?.frame = self.videoView!.layer.bounds
                self.videoView!.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
                self.photoScrollView.addSubview(self.videoView!)
                self.addObserversForVideo()
            }
        })
```

Inside the addObserversForVideo() I set different observers to update a slider that controls the video and also set its min and max values:

```
        guard let currentPlayer = player else {return}
        guard let currentItem = currentPlayer.currentItem else {return}

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.playerFinishedPlayingVideo),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: nil)

        let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.5, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        _ = playerLayer?.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self] (time) in

            self?.videoSlider.maximumValue = Float(currentItem.duration.seconds)
            self?.videoSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
            self?.videoSlider.value = Float(currentItem.currentTime().seconds)
            self?.videoElapsedTimeLabel.text = self?.getStringFromCMTime(time: currentItem.currentTime())

            let remainingTime = currentItem.duration - currentItem.currentTime()
            self?.videoRemainingTimeLabel.text = self?.getStringFromCMTime(time: remainingTime)

        })
```

Now, the problem is that I *sometimes* get this error which crashes my app:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to set a
>   slider's minimumValue (0.000000) to be larger than the maximumValue
>   (nan)'

I don't understand why this happens as I am checking the `currentItem` to be non-nil with a guard statement at the beginning, and also I am setting minimum value after the maximum value. I would appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Comment: You should only set those values when your player's duration is ready. In other words, you should rely on `status` property to know when the player is ready to play. Read more on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/responding_to_playback_state_changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to guard against two additional things:

- `currentPlayer.currentItem.status == .readyToPlay`
- `currentPlayer.currentItem.duration >= CMTime.zero`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @TonyNguyen I could fix the problem in one line:

```
    guard currentItem.status.rawValue == AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay.rawValue else {return}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `periodicTimeObserver` I change the `(time)` to seconds then check if the value is `NaN` or `Infinite` before updating anything.

```
_ = player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self] (time) in

    let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
            
    guard !(seconds.isNaN || seconds.isInfinite) else {
        return
    }

    // the rest of your code
})
```